# Oracle MS SQL data migration

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

What is the best way to import large ammount of data from an Oracle DB to the MS SQL Server 2000? Also, a column mapping facility should be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an ETL tool like Microsoft SSIS or Oracle's Warehouse Builder or Informatica or Ab Initio or something like that.